# rails routes confusing show action with named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

i have a problem implementing a list action with its own route. here is what i have 
(just important parts)
 routes.rb

```
   map.resources :posts   
   map.login  "login" ,:controller => "user_sessions" ,:action => "new" 
   map.logout "logout" , :controller => "user_sessions" , :action => "destroy"
   map.sort "sort" , :controller => "posts" , :action => "sort"
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

 def index
  logger.info "index params:::"+params.inspect
   @posts = current_user.posts.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => 'created_at   DESC'
  end
 end

  def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end


  def sort
   logger.info "sort params:::"+params.inspect
   @posts=current_user.posts.paginate(:page=>params[:page],:order=> params[:sort].to_s )
  if request.xml_http_request?
   render :update do |page|
    page.replace_html :posts , :partial => 'post'    
   end
  end
 end


end
```

I get this error
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show

Couldn't find Post with ID=sort.

I think its because the app thinks that when i type http://localhost:3000/posts/sort i want to show element with id=sort.how can i fix that??
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you are in a REST context. When accessing posts with the :get method, the default routing send the request to the show action, with the :id param set to sort. Try to define the sort action in your routes, something like:

```
map.resources :posts, :collection => {:sort => :get}
```

Set the verb according to your needs, :get seems right since you're just retrieving data.

Then, remove the line

```
map.sort "sort" , :controller => "posts" , :action => "sort"
```

You should now also have a nice url: `sort_posts_url`